# value of type 'cfeedback' cannot be converted to 'system.collections.arraylist'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Firstly, i have a grdData at my main page. After choosing the data i want and went to another page using

```
    Request.QueryString("id")
```

In that page i would like to make another grdData using the

```
    Request.QueryString("id")
```

but came upon an error by

```
    Value of type 'cfeedback' cannot be converted to 'system.collections.arraylist'
```

Below are my codes

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load 
    Dim objArrayList As New ArrayList
    Dim objCDBFeedback As New CDBFeedback
    Dim intGuestID2 As Integer
    intGuestID2 = Request.QueryString("id")
    objArrayList = objCDBFeedback.getFeedBack(intGuestID2)
    grdResult.DataSource = objArrayList


    grdResult.DataBind()

    grdResult.HeaderRow.BackColor = Drawing.Color.AliceBlue
    grdResult.RowStyle.BackColor = Drawing.Color.BlanchedAlmond
    grdResult.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightSalmon

    grdResult.Columns(0).Visible = True


End Sub
```

My Function

```
    Public Function getFeedBack(ByVal pintGuestID1 As Integer) As CFeedback
    Dim objCmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim objCn As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim objAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim strSQL As String = ""
    Dim objDs As New DataSet
    Dim objDataRow As DataRow

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblFeedback WHERE strGuestCodeFB=" & pintGuestID1
    objCmd.CommandText = strSQL
    objCmd.Connection = objCn
    objAdapter.SelectCommand = objCmd

    objCn.Open()

    objAdapter.Fill(objDs, "tblFeedback")
    objDataRow = objDs.Tables("tblFeedback").Rows(0)
    Dim objCFeedback As New CFeedback


    objCFeedback.Feedback = objDataRow.Item("strGuestCompanyTI")

    objCn.Close()
    Return objCFeedback
End Function
```

My Class

```
Public Class CFeedback
Private strGuestCodeFB As Integer
Private strFeedBackFB As String

Public Property GuestId() As String
    Get
        Return strGuestCodeFB
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        strGuestCodeFB = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Feedback() As String
    Get
        Return strFeedBackFB
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        strFeedBackFB = value
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

So is it possible to have a grdData base on querystring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first thing that you need to do is edit your code behind and add the following two lines at the top:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
```

This will show you at least one error: assigning a type of CFeedback to a type of ArrayList.

You will need to determine what the appropriate resolution to this is, but I suspect that you want to return an ArrayList or generic List from GetFeedback instead of just the one item.

So, among other changes, you will want to change pageload to look something like:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim objCDBFeedback As New CDBFeedback
    Dim intGuestID2 As Integer
    intGuestID2 = CInt(Request.QueryString("id"))

    Dim cValues As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of CFeedback)

    cValues = objCDBFeedback.getFeedBack(intGuestID2)

    grdResult.DataSource = cValues
    grdResult.DataBind()

    grdResult.HeaderRow.BackColor = Drawing.Color.AliceBlue
    grdResult.RowStyle.BackColor = Drawing.Color.BlanchedAlmond
    grdResult.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightSalmon

    grdResult.Columns(0).Visible = True

    grdResult.Visible = cValues.Count <> 0
End Sub
```

And the getFeeback method to look something like:

```
    Public Function getFeedBack(ByVal pintGuestID1 As Integer) As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of CFeedback)
        Dim cValues As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of CFeedback)

        Using objCn As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
            Using objCmd As New MySqlCommand
                Dim strSQL As String = ""

                strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblFeedback WHERE strGuestCodeFB=" & pintGuestID1
                objCmd.CommandText = strSQL
                objCmd.Connection = objCn

                objCn.Open()

                Using oReader As MySqlDataReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader
                    Do While oReader.Read
                        Dim objCFeedback As New CFeedback

                        objCFeedback.Feedback = oReader.Item("strGuestCompanyTI")

                        cValues.Add(objCFeedback)
                    Loop
                End Using

                objCn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using

        Return cValues
    End Function
```

Comment: Hi competent_tech, what do i put in CValues ?

Comment: competent_tech..In the database for feedback, there is more than one feedback that i want to display for the grdData. How do i get all the feedbacks that has the same strGuestCodeFB as the "RequestQuerystring".
Because now it is only displaying one feedback when i have 3 with the same strGuestCodeFB.

Comment: Also how do i set that it does not display the grdData if there is no record found in the function getFeedback?

Comment: I have updated the answer to show how to get multiple records (it is actually less code than getting the one answer the way it was setup). To not display the gridData if there is nothing found, the easiest way is to set the visible property to false if there is nothing in the collection. I have updated the answer with this.

Comment: it says my OleDbDataReader is not defined. what should i define it as?

Comment: Sorry, should have been MySqlDataReader. I've fixed the answer

Comment: Thanks but now under my "cmd" that is after MySqlDataReader, it has an error which says its not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. How should i fix this?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I compiled the answer in my code, but since I don't have mysql, I had to use oledb. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Also when i run the file and i chose a record knowing that it has no feedback, it gives me this error
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
for 
grdResult.HeaderRow.BackColor = Drawing.Color.AliceBlue

however if there is feedback, there is no error.
Also if i remove the 
    grdResult.HeaderRow.BackColor = Drawing.Color.AliceBlue
    grdResult.RowStyle.BackColor = Drawing.Color.BlanchedAlmond
    grdResult.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightSalmon

Comment: Do not be sorry. I should be the one saying sorry for asking so many questions. Thanks in advance

Comment: What you probably want to do is only perform those actions if cValues.Count <> 0.